# GetThumbnailAsync() is very slow on VOB files

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, win-universal-app, desktop-bridge

I'm calling:

[storageFile.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.SingleItem);](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.getthumbnailasync)

on a Gigabyte VOB file and it takes over 10 seconds to return. Why is that happening? / How do I fix that?

Even if I were to check if a file is a VOB file in order to know not to call the method, I'm worried there might be other file extensions which will create this problem. So I'd like to know what's behind it.

The app is a WPF (Centennial) app that's calling a UWP method.

I tried using [ThumbnailOptions.ReturnOnlyIfCached](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileproperties.thumbnailoptions) but got many generic icons instead of thumbnails.

Comment: Could you tell how to get `StorageFile` in WPF app?

Comment: I tested `GetThumbnailAsync` within uwp platform, it could get the thumbnail with shot time.